# I need a simple example of a login page in blazor server app without to see or access (in the urls string) any other elements

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, asp.net-authorization

I will shorten my question. xD

So, I use VS2022, C#.

1. Created blazorserverapp with individual accounts using existing VS 2022 template - OK.
2. DB migration to my postgres DB using EF  - done.
3. Login into created website - OK.
4. Login/logout works - OK.

Questions:

1. How can I avoid seeing all elements on the created blazorserver app webpage while I am not logged in?
2. How can I avoid accessing of the webpage elements through entering of the url,  for example: https://localhost:7164/counter while I am not logged in?

What has to be changed in the code to get the  showing/accessing (while not logged in) forbidden?

A simple empty (white) page without any elements, except a little window with user/password fields a and a button inside and in the middle of that empty login page, would be nice.

But something like that, which is actually simple, is not available anywhere – I looked for that for weeks in google…

Everybody is showing/presenting a blazorserver login (individual accounts,  authentication to SQL Server or - for me ideally -  PostgreSQL) example, but:  you can see/access all elements while you are not logged in.

Can somebody provide example of that, pls?

Thx
best

P.S.: Sorry for my bad English (I am from Austria)

That is my MainLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>msgsolutions</PageTitle>
<div class="page">
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
<main>
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <LoginDisplay />
        <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>
    <article class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </article>
</main>
```

And here my Index.razor:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

This is Shared/LoginDisplay.razor:

```
<AuthorizeView>
<Authorized>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
        <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log out</button>
    </form>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
    <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
</NotAuthorized>
```

And here Areas/Identity/Pages/shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="/" method="post">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Nice would be to get this displayed in the middle of a login page.
And this login page has to appear first and no other elements have to be shown on this first page until the user is logged in (example):

```
    <style>


    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
        margin-top: 120px;
        max-width: 400px;
        height: 280px;
        border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
        background: #00BBFF;
    }

    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
        padding: 20px;
    }

        #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form #register-link {
            margin-top: -85px;
        }
</style>

<div id="login">
    <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                    <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                        <EditForm Model=@login>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                                <InputText @bind-Value=@login.user type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <InputText @bind-Value=@login.password type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary" value="Authenticate" @onclick="@(()=>IsLoginValid())"></input>
                            </div>
                        </EditForm>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit (Solved):
We  were able to manage that using   this way: used Index.razor (which contains: "/") and replaced  the content with that:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContext
@using System.Net;

<PageTitle>OurLogin</PageTitle>

<style>


    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
        margin-top: 120px;
        max-width: 400px;
        height: 280px;
        border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    input[type=submit] {
        background: #00BBFF;
    }

    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
        padding: 20px;
    }

        #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form #register-link {
            margin-top: -85px;
        }
</style>

<div id="login">
    <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                    <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                        <EditForm Model=@login>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                                <InputText @bind-Value=@login.user type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                                <InputText @bind-Value=@login.password type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-primary" value="Authenticate" @onclick="@(()=>IsLoginValid())"></input>
                            </div>
                        </EditForm>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>@login.successmsg</p>
@code
{

    public async Task IsLoginValid()
    {
        string hashedpassword = await hashTask;
        string status = await UserAuth(hashedpassword, login.user);
        string successmsg = "";
        if (status == "Authenticated!")
        {
            successmsg = "Authentication successful! Redirecting...";
            Redirect();

        }
        else if (status == "Not Authenticated!")
        {
            successmsg = "Wrong customer ID, username or password! Please try again!";
        }
        else
        {
            successmsg = status;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        login.successmsg = successmsg;
    }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public ErrorHandler? ErrorHandler { get; set; }

}
```

Maybe it helps somebody  who could have similar question.
So the case can be closed.

Comment: Are you using roles? If you are you can simply add - `@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` at the top of each page

Comment: Hello Megan, thank you for your response. I appreciate that. Actually I don't use roles.  I will use that later. What I am trying to achieve is to get the login window without other accessible elements on the first login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same requirement, on a Blazor Server app, and I solved it this way, I hope it will fit your needs. I was inspired by
https://askianoor.medium.com/different-ways-of-authorization-in-blazor-redirect-to-login-blazor-46120d629387.

First, create a distinct layout for the login page, let's call it "LoginLayout.razor"; example:

```
<div class="container py-3">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    @Body
    <LoginError visible="false"/>
</div>
```

Then, create a login page, using the login layout; let's call it "Login.razor":

```
@layout LoginLayout
@page "/login"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<div class="text-center">
    ... your logo or whatever
    <EditForm class="form-signin mb-4" Model="@_credential" OnSubmit="@Authenticate">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-name">User name</label>
            <InputText class="form-control" id="user-name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Indirizzo e-mail" @bind-Value=@_credential.UserName />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <InputText type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" @bind-Value=@_credential.Password />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
        ... other stuff, like "forgot my password", etc...
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    public class Credential { public string UserName { get; set; } = ""; public string Password { get; set; } = ""; }
    private Credential _credential = new Credential();

    private void Authenticate()
    {
        .... perform authentication using _credential fields
    }
}
```

Then, prepare a component which purpose is redirecting to the login page, let's call it "RedirectToLogin.razor":

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? AuthState { get; set; } = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await AuthState!;
        if (authState?.User?.Identity == null || !authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var returnUrl = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login", true);
            else
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login?returnUrl=" + returnUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, most important, modify your App.razor, so that a redirection to the login page is performed, in case the user isn't authenticated:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" >
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Logging in...</p>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Giorgio, can you please provide me an example how to connect / use the check-result (which is true after checking the entered user/pw) of the user/pw to the authState? I could need some piece of code as an example and would be great if you can help me. Thank you

Comment: @BosnianFlajter2 Unfortunately, I'm also struggling on that point. By the way, for various reasons, I'm trying not to use the built-in authentication mechanism. But at the moment I'm stuck. So I can offer neither a "classic" solution, nor a "custom" one.

Comment: ok, thx anyway for your help until now... maybe if somebody is reading this post and knows how to perform auth and use that in authstate can help us. thank you  again and I wish you a nice evening (at least is the evening/night now in Vienna. xD) bye

Comment: @BosnianFlajter2 I have found this video, that is part of a whole series about Blazor, both server and wasm, and I think it is enlightening: https://youtu.be/iq2btD9WufI

Comment: Thx for that info, looked there, reproduced the proposed way described there. It's almost that what we need but... still not a login page displayed first,  one still have to go to the "login button link" on the upper right side to get the login window displayed... :-( - Have you maybe reached some goals in this direction? If yes I would be thankful if you could provide me the way how to do that... thx in advance..

Comment: @BosnianFlajter2 My idea is that if you apply my solution on top of what the video suggests, you should be able to achieve your goal. At the moment I am diverted by another urgent project, but As soon as I go back to blazor, I will try that as well.

Comment: Have any of you been able to do that? @BosnianFlajter2

Comment: Yup, works like a charm - according to the info from Giorgio Barchiesi (YT link he provided). Go to the mentioned youtube link from Giorgio and see my 7 replies there.  - they are ~ 6 months old, you will find that xDD - If you need help, let me know - I can provide some example code of our project which I used according to this youtube  info.